# How to specify domain path of WildFly on NetBeans?

Tags: netbeans-8, wildfly-9

I am trying to add WildFly 9.0.2 to NetBeans IDE 8.0.

I chose "JBoss Application Server" in the "Choose Server" step and I set my "Server Location". But in the 3rd step (Instance Properties), I can't select Domain and Domain Path doesn't appear.
And there is an info "Please specify domain path".

How can I specify domain path?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Install the wildfly plugin, if wildfly isn't in the list.
2. add server -> wildfly...